# In interactive Python development, how can I import from another file?

Tags: python

Say I have the following directory structure:

```
app
|-- A.py
|-- B.py
`-- __init__.py
```

And the content of B.py is:

```
from . import A


def func():
    return 2 * A.bar()
```

If I am developing my app interactively using iPython, how can I execute the contents of B.py? When running the line `from . import A`, python will return an `ImportError`.

EDIT: Ideally I wouldn't want to mess up `sys.path`

Comment: `sys.path` is session based btw, anything you add will be forgotten when you close the program so it's pretty safe

Comment: Do I then always have to hack around sys.path and run a separate `from dir import A`, and then skip the `from . import A` when sending the contents of B.py to the REPL? Seems like either my workflow is broken (likely), or there is a pretty bad usability issue in developing multi-file projects interactively.

Comment: I've never quite understood quite how the `from . import *` syntax works tbf. When I've done multiple files I've called it from the folder above with `absolute_import` enabled, it works well but the main downside is I'm not able to run the files themselves after coding it like that.

Comment: What do you mean by executing the contents of B.py?  There are two ways: `from app import B` if you want to import `B` or `!python -m app.B` if you want to run it as a program.  In both cases there shouldn't be an import error or your python path settings are wrong.

Comment: @BlackJack so you mean I shouldn't have the file `from . import A`? I develop using Emacs with a split screen with my python file on the right, and the REPL on the left. If I run the file by sending blocks to the REPL, then any line containing relative imports will fail.  I just want to learn how to interactively develop with a repl without facing relative import issues. `from app import B` implies that `app` is installed. Is it so that I always have to "install" things before being able to develop them?

Comment: Yes you have to ”install” them, otherwise imports will fail.  Installing can be having the current working directory set so that the top level package can be found, or setting the PYTHONPATH environment variable accordingly, or installing the package in development mode i.e. making it available from the place you are editing it.